# Calculando diferença entre primeira e ultima linha em um pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um dataframe do pandas com cinco linhas 3 três colunas. Eu quero criar uma função onde o meu código retorne as colunas em que a última linha seja maior que a primeira linha. No exemplo do meu código eu quero que ele me gere uma lista com o nome da coluna 'Temp01'. Eu me atrapalhei na hora de criar o if/else para verificar as colunas cuja ultima linha seja maior que a primeira. Abaixo segue meu código:

```
#Importa as Bibliotecas Pandas e Numpy
import pandas as pd

#Cria do Dataframe
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Temp01':[10,20,30,40,15],'Temp02':[50,60,70,70,45],'Temp03':[80,90,100,100,75]})

#Separa Colunas cuja ultima linha seja maior que a primeira
alta =[]#Tendência de Alta

for column in df0.columns: 
  if df0.column[-1]> df0.column[0]:
    text = column
    alta.append(text)
  else:
    pass
print(alta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso você não tenha NaN como primeiro ou último elemento, siga os passos abaixos

### Criando dataframe

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Temp01':[10,20,30,40,15],'Temp02':[50,60,70,70,45],'Temp03':[80,90,100,100,75]})

print(df0)
   Temp01  Temp02  Temp03
0      10      50      80
1      20      60      90
2      30      70     100
3      40      70     100
4      15      45      75
```

### Primeiro elementos

```
first = df0.loc[df0.first_valid_index()]

print(first)
Temp01    10
Temp02    50
Temp03    80
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

### Últimos elementos

```
last = df0.loc[df0.last_valid_index()]

print(last)
Temp01    15
Temp02    45
Temp03    75
Name: 4, dtype: int64
```

### Resultados

```
print(last - first)
Temp01    5
Temp02   -5
Temp03   -5
dtype: int64


resultados = list(last - first)

print(resultados)
[5, -5, -5]
```

Comment: Opa. Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas o resultado me retornou a diferença...mas eu quero q ele me retorne as colunas ("Temp0", "Temp1", "Temp2") cuja última linha seja maior q a primeira. Mas seu código já me ajudou bastante. Grato.

Comment: Opa! bom que ajudou. Fui pego pelo título do post "Calculando diferença entre primeira e ultima linha em um pandas dataframe"